# Convert comma or dot string to single

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion

I would like to convert strings such a "21.7" and "21,7" to single.

I am using

```
    Dim s As String = "21.7" 
    'or Dim s As String = "21,7"
    Dim sng As Single = Single.Parse(s)
```

I thought it would accept both "," and "." as a decimal separator, however it does not because (depending on the decimal separator settings in Windows), I also get 217.

Is there a built-in function that does what I need?

Comment: does "21,7" come from some other culture and maybe from a deserializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the single point is not considered as the decimal separator for some locales that use a comma while for other locales is true the inverse.

A possible solutions to your problem is to try the conversion first using the CurrentCulture and then, if it fails, try with the InvariantCulture

```
Dim s = "21.7"
Dim sng
if Not Single.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, sng) Then
    if Not Single.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, sng) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error conversion")
        return
    End If
End If 
Console.WriteLine(sng)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can really only use one culture at a time, for example:

```
Dim englishUS = "21.7"
Dim englishGB = "21,7"
Const EnUSCultureName = "en-US"
Const EnGBCulterName = "en-GB"
Dim us As Single = Single.Parse(englishUS, New Globalization.CultureInfo(EnUSCultureName))
Dim gb As Single = Single.Parse(englishUS, New Globalization.CultureInfo(EnGBCulterName))
```